# refresh ng-model after sending data

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node-red

my problem is how can i refresh mg-model after sending the data ?? i tried to do this but it doesn't work. any suggestion PLEASE.

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <h3>Nom :{{msg}} </h3><input type="text" ng-model="msg.payload.data1" id="name" name="Nom" placeholder="Nom" size="77"><br><br>
  <h3>Prenom : </h3><input type="text" ng-model="msg.payload.data2" id="prenom" name="Prenom" placeholder="Prenom"  size="77">  <br><br>
  <button id="myBtn_f" ng-click="send(msg);msg={} " ng-disabled="(msg.payload.data1 == null) || (msg.payload.data2 == null)">Enregistrer</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show your javascript? I see nothing here that would disable the input.

Comment: when i try to add second time values and find the input field disabled and my ng-model not empty. i recieve this in my console class ="ng-valid ng-touched ng-dirty ng-empty ng-not-empty-add ng-valid-number-add"